# How can I create a regex that will match several similar strings?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a function that can take multiple strings as an input, and create a regex that will match all of them.

For example, let's say the inputs are:

- fun dog
- funny dog
- fun dogs

It should output something like:

```
/fun(ny)? dogs?/
```

I was wondering if Levenshtein distance could be used for such purpose, but no clue... what do you think?

Comment: Couldn't it just output `/.*/`? After all, your resulting regex also matches more strings than your example strings. Where do you draw the line?

Comment: lol, of course not. It can/have to match in any part of a sentence really.

Comment: But the point is that `fun(ny)? dogs?` matches "funny dogs" which isn't in your list of strings to synthesize from.  Why is that allowed?  Can we allow "funniest dogs" too? Can we allow "fun dogsy"?  Etc ad naus.

Comment: In this specific case (for what i want to use it) singular/plural are acceptable/preferable. Most likely the final regex will end in something like "/fun(ny)? dogs?(\.\s*\w+|$)/" or just "/dogs?\.\w+$/" but i didn't wanted to make my question more complicated by including that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saying which flavor of regex.  Perl comes with a thing called [`Regex::PreSuf`](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/Regex-PreSuf-1.17/PreSuf.pm) which does this sort of thing.

Comment: I've added as tags "php", "javascript", and "c/c++" (ie PCRE) but someone removed/edited them ;) That said, i'll check if i can port that PreSuf to one of those languages, thank you.