# Generate regex expression from series of input

Tags: regex

Is it somehow possible to generate a Regex expression from a series of input ?

I am not sure if this is even possible. Hence I am posting this question here.

Is there any tool or website that does this ?

More Update:
say I enter inputs like

- www.google.com
- google.com
- http://www.google.com

it should somehow give me a regex expression dats accepts this type of input... Is this possible ?

Comment: gonna have to be a lot more specific about what kind of input

Comment: can you provide more details on the question?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt have updated the question

Comment: Too bad we're still in the summer of love, or I would have suggested `def regex(strings): return ".*"`

Comment: On a more serious note: There are tools that try to do such a thing like for example [RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com), but they still require a lot of manual work. I doubt there exists a completely automatic solution that goes beyond just looking for identical substrings.

Comment: thanks for all this information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a regex that will match several similar strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584975/how-can-i-create-a-regex-that-will-match-several-similar-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your URL Example, here's something that I just threw together in C#. I think it'll help you out.

```
    //   Input "pattern" should consist of a string with ONLY the following tags:
    //   <protocol>  <web>  <website>  <DomainExtension>  <RestOfPath>
    //   Ex) GenerateRegexFor("<protocol><web><webite><domainextension>") will match http://www.google.com
    public string GenerateRegexFor(string pattern)
    {
        string regex = ProcessNextPart(pattern, "");
        return regex;
    }

    public string ProcessNextPart(string pattern, string regex)
    {
        pattern = pattern.ToLower();
        if (pattern.ToLower().StartsWith("<protocol>"))
        {
            regex += @"[a-zA-Z]+://";
            pattern = pattern.Replace("<protocol>", "");
        }
        else if (pattern.ToLower().StartsWith("<web>"))
        {
            regex += @"www\d?"; //\d? in case of www2
            pattern = pattern = pattern.Replace("<web>", "");
        }
        else if (pattern.ToLower().StartsWith("<website>"))
        {
            regex += @"([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+";
            pattern = pattern.Replace("<website>", "");
        }
        else if (pattern.ToLower().StartsWith("<domainextension>"))
        {
            regex += "[a-zA-Z]{2,}";
            pattern = pattern.Replace("<domainextension>", "");
        }
        else if (pattern.ToLower().StartsWith("<restofpath>"))
        {
            regex += @"(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)*(\.[a-zA-Z]*/?)?";
            pattern = pattern.Replace("<restofpath>", "");
        }
        if (pattern.Length > 0 && pattern != "")
            return ProcessNextPart(pattern, regex);
        return regex;
    }
```

Depending on the style of URL you'd like to match, I think this should match just about anything and everything. You may want to make it a little more picky if there will be text that is similar to URLs but not URLs.

You'd use it like this:

```
//to match something like "www.google.com/images/whatever"
//            \
//             \                 |www||.google.||----com------||/images/whatever
//              \                  |     |             |              |
//              \/                 V     V             V              V           
string regex = GenerateRegexFor("<web><website><domainextension><restofpath>");
 //to match something like "http://www.google.com/images/whatever"
string regex = GenerateRegexFor("<protocol><web><website><domainextension><restofpath>");
```

You can use any of those tags, in any order (though some of them wouldn't make much sense). Feel free to build on this, too. You could add as many tags as you wanted for it to represent any number of patterns.

Oh, and +1 for giving me something to do at work.